# Only using one GPU

Tags: python

I am running a Keras model trough the TensorFlow API, and have been trying to allocate it to just the first GPU. But TensorFlow still outputs that is using 2 GPU's. How can I change this behavior.

```
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('/GPU:0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow uses an environment variable called `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to determine which GPUs are visible. If the environment variable is not set, Tensorflow will use all of the GPUs on the machine. You can add this to the beginning of the python code to set the environment variable.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```